# Changing the theorem's title style

Tags: theorems, amsthm

I need to change the style of the theorem title ( bold and no ponctuation after the title) :

```
\documentclass[french,a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amstext,amssymb}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{Lettrine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{version}
\usepackage{newcent}
\usepackage{nestochp}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\th@remark{\thm@headpunct{ }}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{Def}{Définition}
\newtheorem*{pre}{Preuve}
\newtheorem{The}{Théorème}
\newtheorem{Lem}{Lemme}
\newtheorem*{Rem}{Remarque}
\newtheorem{pro}{Proposition}
 \numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
```

When I use the code above I got no ponctuation after the theorem's title but the font is not bold.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since,judging by the use of the `remark` style in your example code, you want boldfaced head, no punctuation after the head and normal font for the body, you can easily define a new style with those requirements:

```
\documentclass[french,a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}    

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}% name
  {\topsep}% Space above
  {\topsep}% Space below
  {\normalfont}% Body font
  {}% Indent amount
  {\bfseries}% Theorem head font
  {}%Punctuation after theorem head
  {.5em}%Space after theorem head
  {}% theorem head spec
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{Lem}{Lemme}

 \begin{document}

\begin{Lem}
A test lemma.
\end{Lem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you only want theorems with bold title and no punctuation, this should do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{theorem}
        This is a simple theorem with bold title an no punctuation after the title. 
        As simple as it gets...
        $$a^2+b^2=c^2$$
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You may have missed the fact that the OP loads the `amsthm` package. (Admittedly, he/she didn't make it easy to notice this since the example also loads quite a few other packages that are irrelevant for the issue at hand!) Your answer will have to be modified in order to give the desired result with `amsthm`. Incidentally, the use of `$$` in LaTeX documents is severely deprecated; see, e.g., [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001)